# Bernoulli's equation in a conical pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, bernoulli-equation

**Question**

A stream is rushing from a boiler through a conical pipe, the diameter of ends of which are $D$ and $d$; if $V$ and $v$ are the corresponding velocities of the stream and if the Bernoulli's equation

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{1}\rho\,dp + \frac{1}2q^2 = c
\end{equation}

holds, prove that

\begin{equation}
\frac{v}V = \frac{D^2}{d^2}\exp\left(\frac{v^2-V^2}{2k}\right)
\end{equation}

(The question does not mention what $k$ is.)

**My Approach**

I assume it is a steady flow.
Clearly, the densities at both the ends are different, otherwise $\frac{v}V$ would have been equal to $ \frac{D^2}{d^2}$.

From law of conservation of mass, we have that

$$\rho_1\cdot A_1\cdot v_1 = \rho_2 \cdot A_2 \cdot v_2$$

implying

$$\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{A_2\cdot\rho_2}{A_1\cdot\rho_1}$$

**Doubt**

So we only need to evaluate the density as a function of velocity which could be evaluated through the equation of Bernoulli's. But for that, I must find the relation of density and pressure. I am not sure how to do that. Through further evaluation of pressure, I found that

$$dp = dv + v\frac{d\rho}{\rho}$$

but this on substituting in the original equation seems incorrect.

**Edit**

The question was incomplete. Given, $$k = P/\rho$$

Hence,
$$dp = k\frac{d\rho}{\rho}$$

Substituting this in the Bernoulli's equation gives us

$$k\ln{\rho2/\rho1} + \frac{V^2 - v^2}{2} = 0$$

which on subsituting in the previous continuity equation gives us

\begin{equation}
\frac{v}V = \frac{D^2}{d^2}\exp\left(\frac{v^2-V^2}{2k}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: I imagine that the problem assumes that you have been told what $k$ is somewhere previously... BTW you shoulld  put limits on the integral giving the enthalpy term in Bernoulli.

Comment: Yep, the question was incomplete. I found the correct solution. Thanks a lot for the clarification.